# Purpose of "android:useEmbeddedDex" on Android 10

Tags: android, security, android-security

From here (https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/security-dex), you can see that Android has introduced a new feature that allows code to be run directly from within the APK using embedded dex.

I am curious though how this would be useful?

The guide says:

```
This option can help prevent an attack if an attacker ever managed to 
tamper with the locally compiled code on the device."
```

My understanding is that when your APK is installed, it gets compiled and stored in the dalvik cache as an optimized dex file.  The dalvik cache is only accessible by the system user so unless the phone is rooted, there is no way an attacker can get to it.

If the phone is rooted (and the attacker is running as root), then the embedded dex file can still be tampered with since the attacker can then just modify the apk and re-sign it with their own key.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct. By enabling this option you are forcing the system to run the dex code directly from the .apk file using a JIT compiler (Just like it was on dalvik before Android 4.4) instead of AOT (5+) or a combination of both (4.4-5). You cannot modify and run the dex code inside of an apk without re-signing it, and since you don't have the original signing key you would have to sign it with a different one. As an application developer you can implement code checking the apk signature and checksum and thus not allow running an apk that has been tampered with. What you have in dalvik cache on the other hand, are optimized versions of .dex files and precompiled .oat files which are not signed and thus having root privileges you can modify them.

Comment: Thanks for comment.  How would an application developer check the APK signature if this code has to reside inside the APK itself?  Would it be possible for someone to swap/bypass the method that verifies the APK?

Comment: You can check the APK signature using PackageManager and yes you can remove the code checking it from the app. Speaking of security and tamper protection there are many ways to make the fence higher but it's very hard to make it high enough so that it's impossible to jump over. Check out this talk: https://youtu.be/zOsRc2HI9_k . It's in Polish but you can get something from slides.

Answer (score 0):

Your APK contains your code and the code from the libraries that you add to your
app. That compiled code is packaged as “DEX” files representing Dalvik bytecode.
Smaller apps might have a single DEX file, larger apps might have more than one
(“multidex”).
On Android 4.3 and below, the Dalvik runtime would read the DEX content directly
from the APK. APKs are digitally signed, so there is no way for an outside party to
tamper with the code before Dalvik loads and runs it. This is great from a security
standpoint but adds overhead.

On Android 4.4 and higher, the Dalvik and ART runtimes started pre-processing
those DEX files, including the ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation added in Android
5.0. The output of that work is stored as ordinary files, and so processes with root
privileges could tamper with them. The result is improved app performance at the
cost of weakened security.

Android 10 allows you to set android:useEmbeddedDex to true in your
 element. This tells ART to go back to Android 4.3-style approaches,
avoiding the pre-processing and only using the DEX files packaged in the APK. This
allows developers to opt into the tighter security, for cases where that security is
worth the performance penalties (e.g., no ahead-of-time compilation).